# Is UIWebView's JavaScript evaluator able to use the JS's RegExp object?

Tags: javascript, iphone, regex, uiwebview

There is no default RegEx library on the iPhone. Is it ok if I use UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to evaluate a JavaScript string that actually uses the RegExp object to evaluate an expression? Is this supported on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, here's a sample code. The idea behind doing it this way might be to support Javascript-compliant Regular Expressions, leading to reuse and portability of existent JS Regexp code you might have:

```
UIWebView *wb = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [wb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                          @"re = new RegExp('su{1,3}p+er'); re.test('suuuper')"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can always just try it and find out, but there's probably another way to get what you need.  The `NSPredicate` class, for example, allows string matching on regular expressions.  If you need to do searching, I'm not sure about that, but take a look at [this article](http://www.stiefels.net/2007/01/24/regular-expressions-for-nsstring/) for matching anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is the BSD "C" regex library on the iPhone, I have used it in a couple of apps.
[man:regex](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/regex.3.html)